# Pull dates from undefined number of sheets to Summary sheet matching the sheet name to the data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a spreadsheet for work that compiles all of our lab schedules for any given job. The spreadsheet consists of a summary sheet that will give the important information from every lab schedule, and a sheet for every single lab schedule. We could get a variable number of these lab schedules in for a given job so we could be working with 2 sheets or 10 sheets (not including the summary sheet), etc. Hopefully that gives you a bit of an insight into what we need it for.

I've been trying to patch together a code to pull the dates from every lab schedule sheet through to the summary sheet. The dates would need to go into a table matching both the column heading (i.e. Due Date, Received Date, etc) and the 'Lab No'(also the name of the tabs i.e. L1234). With regards to the dates, ignore the 'Geo, Chem, Wac' as I've taken the most recent date out of the three and put that below them. I've attached a few images of the workbook so you can see what sort of structure I've got.

Lab Schedule Sheet:

[image: Lab Schedule Sheet]

Summary Sheet:

[image: Summary Sheet]

Comment: "excel-vba-mac" tag based on your screenshots. On each lab schedule sheet, are the most recent dates in the same range (C12:E12)?

Comment: Ahh yes, I've had to make a example sheet on my personal laptop but the actual workbook will be on windows. Yes they are the most recent dates, I plan on hiding that row but it was the most simple way I could think of getting the most recent date for each column

Comment: But is the table on each schedule sheet in the same range? Maybe you can use `INDIRECT`.

Comment: Yes it is. I tried using indirect earlier but couldn't get it to link to the LabNo whenever I created a new sheet. Basically I want to create a button that will fetch/update the dates on the summary sheet for every LabNo/Schedule on it

Comment: What do you mean by "link to the LabNo whenever I created a new sheet"? Do you want VBA to list out all the Lab Schedules (L1234, etc.) on the Summary Sheet or are you typing those in manually? If you do the INDIRECT right you should be able to drag formulas down.

Comment: Oh I think I understand how I can use that now. I'd insert new columns in the Summary sheet that would give the constant cell reference for the column headings within the Lab Schedules. Hopefully should work the way I want it to! Thanks for your help!